# How can I share Civ 5 DLCs with different user accounts on the same PC?

Tags: steam, civilization-5

On one computer I have 3 different users of Steam:

- The first user bought Civilization 5 some time ago (basic no DLC),
- The second user bought Civ 5 and all DLCs.

I've also selected the option to 'share games with other accounts on the computer' (where I checked the first user too).

It is possible to access the games of the 2nd user by the 1st user, but Civ5 can't access the DLCs. It is not a simultaneous login (i.e. it is either user 1 or user 2 that is logged in, not both at the same time). I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling and changing various settings, but can't seem to make it work.

Is what I want to do possible? Can I share DLCs for various games between accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately [Steam Family Sharing](http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing) only shares game DLC with another user, if that user does **not** own the game.
If the loaning user also owns the game, they won't be able to acces the DLC of the "main" account. They'll have to buy the DLC as well. I'm not aware of a way to get around this limitation. If you want to take drastic measures, Steam's support may be able to remove the game from the 1st user's account, but they propably won't compensate you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  It is really crap that they don't allow for the dlcs to be shared.  Is it maybe a way to "temporarily" remove the civ5 from the 1st user's account so that it could play the 2nd user dlcs.  Maybe remove it from the library or something?  Or is there a way to move civ5 from the 1st user account to another account (4th user)?

Comment: @aretai Not that I know of. I think the best you can do is to contact Steam Support, explain your situation. I doubt they'll move the Civ5 to completely different account. They might help removing it from your library (as in, as if it was never owned at all), but this will likely be a permanent thing, _not_ temporary.

Comment: @ DJ Pirtu - you may be wrong here - http://steamcommunity.com/groups/familysharing/discussions/0/405693392920127406/?tscn=1457225632

Comment: @aretai Interesting read. I'm a bit skeptical if the Steam Support will restore the game as automaticly as is suggested, but I can see how this could work. However, I have very little experience in this kind of thing.

Comment: I was told restoring game is an automatic process